# How to log client IP Address using LogBack

Tags: micronaut

I am using micronaut 1.2.5, I need to log the client IP Address.

this is my logback.xml

```
<configuration>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <withJansi>true</withJansi>
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%cyan(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}) %gray([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %magenta(%logger{36}) - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

i need to log the client ip address.

I see the latest [docs already have this feature.](https://docs.micronaut.io/2.0.1/guide/index.html#distributedConfigurationConsul)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i need to log the client ip address.

You can use a [HttpClientAddressResolver](https://docs.micronaut.io/1.2.5/api/io/micronaut/http/server/util/HttpClientAddressResolver.html) to resolve the client IP address.

```java
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus;
import io.micronaut.http.server.util.HttpClientAddressResolver;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Controller("/demo")
public class DemoController {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoController.class);

    private final HttpClientAddressResolver addressResolver;

    public DemoController(HttpClientAddressResolver addressResolver) {
        this.addressResolver = addressResolver;
    }

    @Get("/")
    public HttpStatus index(HttpRequest request) {
        LOG.debug("The client ip address is {}.", addressResolver.resolve(request));
        return HttpStatus.OK;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this in `logback.xml` ?

Comment: No, but you could use a `HttpFilter` and put the IP in the `MDC` for logback

Comment: @Bobby There is an example in the [documentation](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#filters) on how to write a filter

Comment: Sorry, this is made by micronaut. Is there a similar solution for Spring Boot? Thanks